# Hi , can anyone help me in configuring JUnit framework for testing purposes?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5

I have downloaded the JAR files and added them in the project's build path under libraries. However, when I try to run the code, it's giving me this error message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/ConfigurationParameters

I have added JUnit in module path only as I am unable to add it in class Path. When I add JUnit5 to class path, I don't get apply button activated. It doesn't get enabled.

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Use Maven or Gradle and add the test dependency following any of the thousands of available tutorials and this just works. It can still be done as in the 1990s, but why bother?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time and kind suggestions. I am able to run it now.